# HTML Table colspan rowspan

Tags: html, html-table

I have 6 columns & I want to use `colspan` for 3&4 and 5&6 column.
And I don't want to show 1st & 2nd column for that particular row.

How to hide 1&2 column in that row?

Desired output..

[image]

Comment: It is like putting heading above columns.

Comment: Can you upload an image of what you want as output?

Comment: @KunJ please see image

Comment: You can remove the border of first 2 cells to achieve it, logically not possible not skip cells like this. See @misterManSam answer. He has done exactly you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the border from the cells you wish to "hide". They are still there, but visually absent.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/wgWDK/)

[Experimental fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgWDK/3/)  for a `table { border: xxx; }` fix.

In this example I am targeting the cell with `tbody tr:first-child td:first-child`. This could obviously also be targeted with a `class`.

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 500px;
}
td {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Good answer! You did exactly he wants :) +1 for this.

Comment: Its perfect. But.. Actually this is not related to this question but, i have border set for table also. so in this case though i `border:none` for cell, i can still see that table border in that area.

Comment: Do you need that border on the table? That's when we get creative. Have a [look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgWDK/3/). It works in latest Chrome and Firefox, but it will probably have issues with other browsers. Unfortunately, there is not much you can do apart from this hack. `visibility:hidden` does not remove the border in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:none;` in your CSS File on the 1st & 2nd Column.

You can select them with:

```
td:nth-of-type(1),
td:nth-of-type(2) {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: if `display: none` then positions changes for colspan.

Answer (score 0):

Use `visibility:hidden` on the first two columns of the row.

Comment: i can set table `border=0` but it affects other part of table.

Comment: here is my update on @misterManSam 's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgWDK/5/).
It didn't need the `after` part as lon as you disable the border of the whole table

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `visibility: hidden; empty-cells: hide;` for that cells.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darshak/68Bjm/)

HTML

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: 0;">a1</td>
            <td colspan="2">a3</td>
            <td colspan="2">a5</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>5555</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Hi @user3785624! In the future please include relevant code snippets when posting an answer with a fiddle. Please have a look at the contents of my edit to your post for an example :)